# How to embeb browser window in app with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this project and i need to embeb a browser window on the right frame.
You can see the schema on the picture below.

I can make the browser but cant seem to implement it with the schema because its tkinter and the browser uses PyQt5.

Is there a way to do this with tkinter or a way to use booth GUI toolkit?

the check box is to choose if the link open on external browser or the in app browser locate just bellow the checkbox.

i dont need to use PyQt5 but i have everything in tkinter, i just need to find the best way to have a browser inside the app.

thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: There is an [example](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tkinter_.py) on embedding a browser in tkinter using `cefpython`.

Comment: acw1668 thanks, this seems to do the thing, but now im i get raise Exception("Python version not supported: " + sys.version)
Exception: Python version not supported: 3.9.4 (v3.9.4:1f2e3088f3, Apr  4 2021, 12:32:44) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]

does this need to have a lower python version?

Comment: i think cefpython3 wont work with python 3.9 :(

Comment: manage to fix it installing an unoficial package for 3.9

Comment: know i juest need to implement it thank you :)

Comment: You need to install `cefpython3`.

Comment: i had, it was a issue with the python version

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by acw1668, cefpython is the way.

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tkinter_.py